# Editing a PDF file with Java

Tags: java, pdf, printing, itext

I'm trying to edit a existing PDF file. It is a file where I need to fill in some addresses and other stuff. I want to connect an addressbook to the application so the user can select a user from the addressbook and a part get filled in automatic.

My questions are:

1. Is it possible to edit a existing PDF file and fill in some fields (+/- 20), because I know there is Itext (http://www.itextpdf.com) but I read that the possiblities are very small.
2. Or can I better convert the PDF to JPG and get it as background. And create JLabels on the places where I need to fill in the fields. And then print the whole Frame on a A4.
3. Or are there better posibilities?

So what I need to do, step by step:

- Select one of the PDF's (they are in the program)
- Fill some fields with content/addresses
- Print the PDF/Form with a printer

Answer (score 1):

There is a toolkit given by Adobe named as  [Acrobat Forms Data Format (FDF) Toolkit](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/fdftoolkit.html) which gives API for different languages to fill forms.

You can get the java code at the bottom of that page or check this [link](http://download.macromedia.com/pub/developer/acrobat/FDFToolkitForJava.zip)

Comment: I looked very quick. And I think this can be very usefull. Did you work with it? So yes, Can I add some buttons to a existing PDF, for example a button to open a Java Application Addressbook and click on an Item and set it automatic in the PDF (FDF)?

Comment: I also see that I need a server to be run. I can't use it on the same machine as the client machine..

Comment: No I have heard about it from some other developers, but I don't have any personal experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pdf form and edit field values programmatically using [IText](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=157) or [Apache PDFBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/fdf/SetField.html) (download pdfbox and see SetField.java example)

Comment: Is it possible to edit a existing PDF file and fill in some fields (+/- 20), because I know there is Itext (http://www.itextpdf.com) but I read that the possiblities are very small. Have you an example or something?

Answer (score 0):

We didn't edit existing PDF's but created totally new letters/reports/doco from our java app using [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport)

Comment: Hmm I need it for a customer, So I don't think this is good enough for my Customer. Because he has to do to much. It needs to be simple!